# Capitalization of interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

I've got quiet a strange problem but a simple one I guess. So I have a starting sum of 10 and I would like to know how many years need to pass to achieve 30000 with 32% interest applied every 2 years.
There's an equation for such problems:

```
K = Ko (1 + p / (100*m) )^(m*n)
```

where K is the target sum, Ko is the starting sum, p is the percent, m is how many times an interest is applied in a year and n is years.
I took K = 30000, Ko = 10, p = 32, m = 1/2, n - the unknown.
Following this pattern I got to such equation:

```
n = log_(sqrt(1,64)) (30000 / 10) = 32,36...
```

based sqrt(1,64) logarithm of (30000/10)

Secondly to check the correctness of this equation I've written a simple program in C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int total = 30000;
    int current = 10;
    int n = 0;

    while(current < total)
    {
        current = current * 1.32;
        n+=2;
    }
    printf("%d", n);
    _getch();
}
```

which gives me n = 60. I know this program is inaccurate and won't give a precise result but such difference between results proves that one solution must be wrong? The program is very simple and it seems to me correct so I guess that the mathematical formula above doesn't work in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems.

**Problem 1**. You quote a formula `K = Ko (1 + p / (100*m) )^(m*n)` But the formula you're trying to implement should have `(1 + p / 100)` rather than `(1 + p / (100*m))`.

$$\begin{align}
K &= K_0 ( 1+ p/100)^{mn} \\
\log\frac{K}{K_0} &= mn \log(1+p/100) \\
n &= \frac{1}{m}\frac{\log(K/K_0)}{\log(1+p/100)} \\
&= 2\frac{\log(30000/10)}{\log(1.32)}
\end{align}
$$

Evaluating `2*log(30000/10)/log(1.32)` gives `57.67617`, i.e. 58 rounded up to the nearest two years.

**Problem 2**. You use `int` in your program when you should use `double`. Once you correct your program, as below, you get 58 not 60 out of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double total = 30000;
    double current = 10;
    int n = 0;

    while(current < total)
    {
        current = current * 1.32;
        n+=2;
    }
    printf("%f final, %d", current, n);
}
```

([ideone online program](http://ideone.com/S0kKqj))

Comment: You mean that the formula I quoted is commonly correct but in my case I shouldn't divide the "p" by m, right?

Comment: @Savail I mean that for the way you described your problem in words  "with 32% interest applied every 2 years" and the way you implemented it in C, the formula should not have the `/m`. As for when the formula you quoted _does_ apply, that's a different question. But the typical case would be something like annual interest rate of 32%, interest compounded twice yearly, so 16% applied every 6 months. Here `m=2` means twice yearly and `n` is the number of years.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in how "$32\%$ interest applied every $2$ years" is interpreted in the methods.

The compound interest formula is for a *yearly rate*. As in over a period of one year, if your interest was not compounded, how much would your money increase? The issue is that the rate you have is not a yearly rate. It's the rate for every two years.

Notice the $1.64$ you have there? That's $1+0.32\cdot2$. Put that into a two year period, where interest should only be applied once and not compounded at all yet. You expect $13.2$, but get
$$\left(1+\frac{32}{100\cdot0.5}\right)^{0.5\cdot2}=1.64$$
You've doubled your rate. Use a rate of $16\%$, a yearly rate, and you get an answer of $57.68$ years. In reality it would be $58$, since you need to reach the next interest payout period.

As for why your program is getting $60$ instead of $58$, int casting rounds every payout down to the nearest dollar. You're losing a bit of money each time and the error, quite appropriately, compounds.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Translating 32% every two years is equivalent to finding the yearly rate as below:

$$1.32 = (1+p)^2$$

$$p = (1.32)^{0.5} -1 = 0.1489125$$

Now simply apply the formula $K = K_0\left(1+p\right)^n$

Now $$n = \frac{log(\frac{K}{K_0})}{log(1.1489125)} = 57.67616963$$